# How To Set Font Awesome Icon in Magento Top Links?

Tags: magento-1.9, toplinks

How To Set Font Awesome Icon in Magento Top Links? In Magento Customer.xml

app\design\frontend\mytheme\default\layout\customer.xml

[image]

Comment: You could add class's to each link and then assign that way.

Comment: but how to add that, and what is the proper way,that i don't know,

Comment: i have use 
**<block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link">
            <action method="setBeforeText">
                <beforeText><![CDATA[<i class="fa fa-gift"></i>]]>    </beforeText>
            </action>**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Get Solution In header.php Like..

```
<div class="submenu">                               
<ul class="submenu-link">
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>customer/account" ><i class="fa fa-user"></i> My Account</a></li>
<li><?php echo ucfirst($this->getChildHtml('minicart_head')); ?></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>wishlist" ><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> Wishlist</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>checkout" ><i class="fa fa-crosshairs"></i> Checkout</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>checkout/cart" ><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Cart</a></li>
<?php if (Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ): ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>customer/account/logout"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i> Logout</a></li>
<?php   else: ?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()?>customer/account/login"><i class="fa fa-sign-in"></i> Login</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>                           
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work. For magento 1 anyway.

In your layout file:

```
<reference name="wishlist_link">
    <action method="setAParams">
        <param><![CDATA[class="fa fa-icon"]]></param>
    </action>
</reference>
```

Comment: OP's magento is 1 not 2.

Comment: Apologies i thought it was 2. I have altered for mage 1